# Haskell : convert a bytestring to [word8]

Tags: haskell

my intent is to convert a `bytestring` to a `List of Word8` in haskell in order to get access to the LSB for each `byte`.

any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
unpack :: ByteString -> [Word8]
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:unpack

Also consider whether you can skip the intermediate list, and directly use [`foldl'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:foldl-39-) or some related fold.

Comment: For instance `foldr (\w r -> w .&. 1 : r) []` will lazily produce a list of the least significant bits. The line noise version is `foldr ((:) . (1 .&.)) []`.

Comment: the signature of `unpack` is `ByteString -> [GHC.Word.Word8]` is there any difference between `Data.Word8` and `GHC.Word.Word8`

Comment: Yes, they are the same, in GHC. The `Data.Word8` is the public version you should use. Internally, that is a re-export of the GHC internal implementation of `Word8`.